# Как преобразовать строку к нужному мне формату?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо описать класс Name. Экземпляр класса создается одной строкой, состоящей из 2-3 слов (на это нужна проверка). Нужно описать метод **strfname(format)**, который преобразует строку по переданному формату, где

%Ф - фамилия,

%ф - первая буква фамилии,

%И - имя,

%и - первая буква имени

%О - отчество,

% - первая буква отчества

Например: Name.strfname('%и. %о. %Ф') - И. И. Иванов

Подскажите, как можно описать метод strfname?

```
class Name:

def __init__(self, fio):
    if 2<=len(fio.split())<=3:
        self.fio = fio
    else:
        print('Введите корректное значение')
```

Comment: в строке через замену `.replace` проходите и меняете псевдокод на текст, т.е. для 6ти вариантов у вас будет 6ть `.replace`

Comment: Ну, например, берёте форматную строку и тупо делаете на ней `.replace('%Ф', поле_где_у_вас_фамилия)` и т.д.

Comment: Было бы не плохо примеры входных данных глянуть. Честно говоря не очень понятно как Вы в исходной строке будете мапить где у вас фамилия где имя, а где отчество и определеять в строке из двух слов это имя-фамилия или имя-отчество

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то в качастве идеи могу предложить вариант, если понравится соберите из него класс или функцию

```py
fio = 'Семенов;Ареадий;Петрович'
surname, name, patronymic = fio.split(';')

text = 'Получатель %фамилия %и%о'

strfmt = [
    ('%и', name[0].upper() + '.'),
    ('%ф', surname[0].upper() + '.'),
    ('%о', patronymic[0].upper() + '.'),
    ('%имя', name.capitalize()),
    ('%фамилия', surname.capitalize()),
    ('%отчество', patronymic.capitalize())
]

for pat, val in sorted(strfmt, key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True):
    text = text.replace(pat, val)

print(text)
# Получатель Семенов А.П.
```